# Comparison operators not working (in erb views)

Tags: ruby

I'm pretty new to Ruby on Rails, and I'm trying to write a more than expression:

```
<% if current_member.photo_limit > 5 %>
```

the greater than symbol keeps throwing an Exception caught error.  I'm not sure how to fix this?

Edit: This isn't rails, or the view, its a Ruby construct

Comment: what is the actual error?  Is it being thrown *in textmate*(?) or on execution of the view?

Comment: in the rendering/view     undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass

Comment: this should really be tagged as just `ruby` and not rails or textmate

Comment: thanks - I didn't know if it was an editor or language issue.

Answer (score 5):

use 
    <% if current_member.photo_limit.to_i > 5 %>

the error is from photo_limit not extending from the `Integer` class (guessing its really a string), and therefore not having the mixed-in comparison method/s

For more about that, see: http://www.skorks.com/2009/09/ruby-equality-and-object-comparison/

specifically you have to mix in `Comparable` and define the `<=>` method.

using String.to_i should be fine here though...

Comment: Thanks but the count isn't in the DB table, I've got it stored in the model (to keep the DB queries down)

Comment: Doesn't matter where it is stored, how do you have photo_limit defined in the model?